# Using tabindex="0" creates impact on other elements

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I tried to add tabindex="0" to make unfocussed elements to focus. I added javascript code as well to fire Enter key on focus elements.I have two anchor link one with href value and another without href. I added tabindex="0" to non href anchor tag.

```
 <a onclick="ob_os(this)" href="/ic/project/Headlines/headlines.asp" target="main">Home</a>
  <a tabindex="0" onclick="ob_os(this)">Documents</a>
```

ob_os() is function that expand and collpase elemets.But after adding tabindex="0" to second link there is a impact on first link. When focus is there on first link and firing Enter key it is not expanding while second link is expanding.

```
    function ob_os(e){
    var os = e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.firstChild;
if (os != null) {
if ((typeof os != "undefined") && (os.tagName == "IMG")) {
    var lensrc = (os.src.length - 8);
    var s = os.src.substr(lensrc, 8);
    if ((s == "inus.gif") || (s == "usik.gif")) {
        e.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.firstChild.click();
    }
}
else {
    ob_os(e.parentNode);
}
```

}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second link is really a button and should be assigned a role as such. A link is for navigating to pages or views while a button is for interactive elements on the page. Using `javascript:void(0);` in the href will prevent the page from scrolling to the top while also being recognized correctly by screen readers.

```
<a onclick="ob_os(this)" href="/ic/project/Headlines/headlines.asp" target="main">Home</a>
  <a role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ob_os(this)">Documents</a>
```

Comment: or make the second element a real button, `<button onclick="ob_os(this)">Documents</button>`

Answer (score 1):

As an `<a>` without the `href` attribute is not perceived as a link by screen readers, Do the following:

1. Remove your `tabindex`, you won't need it.
2. Add the `link` ARIA role to your anchor.

The result would look like this:

```
<a onclick="ob_os(this)" href="/ic/project/Headlines/headlines.asp" target="main">Home</a>
<a role="link" onclick="ob_os(this)">Documents</a>
```

Comment: And to get default cursor behavior include an empty `href` attribute. Actually, that alone may resolve the issue.

Comment: adding ARIA role to anchor tag not received as a link

Comment: the `role` would make it a link but still not allow you to tab to it.  you'd still need `tabindex`.  and adding a role doesn't give the element any **behavior** of a link, that would have to be added too.  you'd need keyboard handlers.  a real link would fire the onclick when you click with the mouse or hit enter with the keyboard, but this isn't a real link so you'd need to trap the keyboard event.